# TradingView advance chart has Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'startsWith')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tradingview-api

During implementation TradingView with Reactjs based on Tradingview's documentation step by step so I found that I had two error's inside console as follows:
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'startsWith')`  also `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')`. For additional information, I applied for official Tradingview advance chart so I already have charting_library path. Does anyone encountered this error during implementation Tradingview with React js? Thanks for the pay attention..

Answer (score 0):

The function of tradingview has changed

The previous parameter was:

```
getBars(symbolInfo, resolution, from, to, onHistoryCallback, onErrorCallback, firstDataRequest)
```

Now the parameters are:

```
 getBars = (
    symbolInfo,
    resolution,
    from,
    onHistoryCallback,
    onErrorCallback,
)
```

Among them, the `from` parameter contains `from`, `to` and `firstDataRequest`

Please check the order of the `onHistoryCallback` parameters you are using